# How work with Word and Excel in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, ms-office, ole

I use Delphi X10 and Word 2016 64-bit on Windows 10 64-bit.
I always used ComObj.
for example:

```
uses ComObj;


procedure TForm1.RzBitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var Excel: variant;  i, j: word;
begin
  Excel := CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
  Excel.Workbooks.Open('file.xls');
  for i := 1 to 5 do
  for j := 1 to 5 do
  StringGrid1.Cells[j, i] := Excel.Sheets[1].Cells[i, j].Text;
end;
```

But, i want to use autocompleate for Excel methods. I read what i should import type library, but i cant find type library file in my system.

Comment: So, what is the question? If there is no type library present in the system, how can we help? Just check if they are installed by the Office setup (maybe they are not by default).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite easy to do, as long as the type libraries for Excel anmd Word are correctly registered.

Go to the OCX\Servers folder under your Delphi install and find Word2010.Pas.  Add it to a new VCL project, and USE it in the main form's unit.  Declare a form variable `A: WordApplication` on your main form.

With that done, you should be able to go to Form1's Form.Create, type

```
A.
```

and autocomplete should offer you the possibilities for WordApplication's methods and properties.

Now, open Word2010.Pas and find the section

```
// File generated on 2/20/2013 5:56:45 PM from Type Library described below.

// ************************************************************************  //
// Type Lib: c:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\msword.olb (1)
// LIBID: {00020905-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}
```

That tells you the name and location of the type library which was used to generate Word2010.Pas.

Now, unless you need to use some method/property that has been added to Word/Excel since the 2010 version, Word2010.Pas and Excel2010.Pas  may be all you need.  However, you can import the type library of a more recent version using Delphi and have it generate an import unit for it.  Exactly how to do that depends on your Delphi version, but for Delphi Seattle. you simply go to Component | Import Component from the IDE main menu, then select `Import type library` in the pop-up and follow the wizard's prompts.

Once you've generated the import unit, obviously you simply USE it in your project instead of MSWord2010.

Btw, strictly speaking, there is no "Delphi X10", recent versions (since XE8) have been Seattle, Berlin and Tokyo.

Comment: Thanks for answer.
Problem is that seems no type library in system, maybe because office is 64-bit. No word or Excel, only some Office. https://ibb.co/jQ7QTF

Comment: Sounds like the first thing you might do is to verify whether or not Word2010.Pas works on your system.  If not, you need to find the names of the 64-bit type libraries for Excel and Word, register them if you can, and refer e.g. to https://bobsotherblog.wordpress.com/2013/09/19/import-64bit-type-libraries-in-delphi/ for how to import them.  Seems potentially a troublesome process if all you are wanting is to get autocomplete in the IDE.